# View produces blank page on POST

Tags: django

Django displays the page fine when I open it from menu (without sending data). But when I post data through a form Django produces a white blank page. No error message in console.

This is my urls.py

```
url(r'^signin', myView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='signin'),
```

This is my views.py

```
class myView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(myView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.path == '/signup':
            context.update(self.create_user())
        return context

    def create_user(self):
        data = {}
        if self.request.POST:
            if 'email' in self.request.POST and 'user' in self.request.POST \
            and 'password' in self.request.POST:
                User.objects.create_user(self.request.POST['user'],
                                         self.request.POST['email'],
                                         self.request.POST['password'])
                data['msg'] = _('User created')
            else:
                data['error'] = _("Incomplete data")
        return data
```

This is my console log when I post data:

```
"POST /signin HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

I already set `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`. What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: ` 405 Method Not Allowed` that is your error, you're missing your post method

Comment: Dont use a `TemplateView` for this. If you insist on using CBV's go with the convention and use a `CreateView`. Your successors will thank you.

Comment: @limelights thanks. I will change my code. I lack complete example on this issue.

Comment: @asofyan the docs are really good at explaining this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement post method.

```
class MyView(View):
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your save logic
```

Also you can use CreateView for your requirement.

[Documentation: django.views.generic.edit.CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method `create_user` to `post` or define `post` method and call your method from it.

Generic view need to have appropriate method to handle request types.

```
class myView(TemplateView):

    def post(self):
        return self.create_user()

    ... 
    #your view code
```